# Sending location data every minute or so, any solution?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to send location data to my express backend within 30 minute spaces.

```
try {
    setInterval(async () => {
      getLocationData();
    }, 180000);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

This is the code that I use to fetch data about location to send back to the server. I get warnings when I run this code that I shouldn't try to fetch data like this. How should I go about sending location data to the backend.

(I know that 180000 is not half an hour)

Comment: what's the exact warning? can you take a SS and post it?

Comment: Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
(Saw setInterval with duration 180000ms)